# selecting a subset of data based on another column

Tags: r

I have a dataset which looks something like this:

```
     Area     Num
[1,] "Area 1" "99"  
[2,] "Area 3" "85"  
[3,] "Area 1" "60"  
[4,] "Area 2" "90"  
[5,] "Area 1" "40"  
[6,] "Area 3" NA    
[7,] "Area 4" "10" 
...
```

code:

```
structure(c("Area 1", "Area 3", "Area 1", "Area 2", "Area 1", 
"Area 3", "Area 4", "99", "85", "60", "90", "40", NA, "10"), .Dim = c(7L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Area", "Num")))
```

I need to do some calculation on values in `Num` for each `Area`, for example calculating the sum of each `Area`, or the `summary` of each `Area`.

I'm thinking of using a `nested` for loop to achieve this, but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: First, I suggest you to use data.frame instead of matrix when columns have different types (your example dataset is a matrix, where the second column has probably been converted from numeric to character because matrices support only one element type)

Comment: Then, you don't need a loop to perform these aggregated calculations, e.g. you can use `by`, `aggregate` or `split` function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `aggregate`, but the `dplyr` package makes it very easy to work with such problems. There are plenty of duplicates of this question, though.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(c("Area 1", "Area 3", "Area 1", "Area 2", "Area 1", 
                  "Area 3", "Area 4", "99", "85", "60", "90", "40", NA, "10"), .Dim = c(7L, 
                                                                                        2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Area", "Num")))


df <- data.frame(df)
df$Num <- as.numeric(df$Num)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Area) %>%
  summarise(totalNum = sum(Num, na.rm=T))

df2
```

Comment: I think you should update your answer to inculde na.rm =True, otherwise Area 3 will be NA

Answer (score 2):

In order to apply the function to every level of the factor, we can recurse to the `by` function:

```
dt <- structure(c("Area 1", "Area 3", "Area 1", "Area 2", "Area 1", 
              "Area 3", "Area 4", "99", "85", "60", "90", "40", NA, "10"), .Dim = c(7L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Area", "Num")))


dt <- data.frame(dt)
dt$Num <- as.numeric(dt$Num)

t <- by(dt$Num, dt$Area, sum)
t
```

Comment: This works, but is not an ideal solution; the actual dataset contains many different "area". Naming them one by one is simply not feasible.

Comment: My fault. I edited the question with a more proper solution. I hope it works properly.

Comment: yes it is great! I'm trying to learn the different ways to do one thing.

Comment: I am happy that you find it useful!

Answer (score 1):

Doing the same thing using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(df)

dt[,sum(as.numeric(Num),na.rm=T),by=Area]
##         Area  V1
##    1: Area 1 199
##    2: Area 3  85
##    3: Area 2  90
##    4: Area 4  10
```